# Javascript performance difference in creating elements vs detach and append modified element?

Tags: jquery, performance, polymer, detach

Stumbled upon this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2UKPRbrw3Kk and the concept of reusing the same elements on page to reduce redraws is interesting.

In a large list html elements (10000+) with on page scroll to show more, what would be an efficient way of showing the content? Using Replace? Detach and Append? Something else?

At the moment, all elements loaded into the DOM and only the first X visible and the rest set to display none. On page scroll shows the new sets of hidden elements .This is not ideal performance-wise.

Thinking of two possible methods to use:

- Load the data in a json and create new elements on page.
- Detach the first element and append to bottom elements, wait for
  scroll to end    to calculate which position to show new content.

What would be the better route performance-wise? Am I simply wrong about how the browser handles these elements?

Comment: Write a microbenchmark if you are curious. The benefit of (really any one of these approaches) is the number of elements in the DOM at any one point is "significantly less" than the total amount of data. This is also know as virtual scrolling / virtual paging. An element cache and moving can be used but *the big benefit comes from having "significantly less" elements in the DOM*.

Comment: Thanks for insights. Learned some new terms today, that will help in finding more effective search results in google.